# Empty declaration in css causes IE8 bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I think I have encounter an IE8 bug, but I'm not sure...

I can't provide a testcase because my css are more than 2500 lines long (half-minified), and can't recreate exact conditions.

**The problem**

In my huge css sheet, I have an empty declaration as this:

```
.class {}
```

Well, I usually do this to start the cascade, and delete the line later, this time I forgot.

Then, testing the page, there was two or three classes who literally dissapear. It's like there's no css rule for that elements. <strike>The lost css seems to be random, nothing to do with the empty rule, or the cascade.</strike> **The lost element is the next from the empty rule**.

If I have:

```
.class {}
.otherclass {color:red;}
```

Then, IE8 don't show me red color in `otherclass` element.

I find this page as a testcase:
 http://css-class.com/test/bugs/ie/8-beta/empty-declaration-hides-next-ruleset.htm

This bug [is supposed to be fixed](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/ie8.html). So, I saw that testcase in IE8 and I can't see any difference with FF or CH or other IE versions. But in our website I can! It's building with Zope/Plone, if it helps.

Is there any official sources that recognises this bug? Anyone knows why sometimes (or in Plone) works and sometimes not?

Comment: That's weird; I've not seen that before. The only thing I can suggest is maybe the empty line also contains some kind of invalid white-space character that is throwing IE's parser for a loop? You say that deleting the line makes it work; does it break again if you retype the line from scratch (as opposed to simply undo-ing or pasting the original back)? The only other thing I can think of is maybe you're on the edge of a file size limit? IE8 does have limits on the number of CSS files and their size; possibly you're right on the edge of that? What happens if you delete other lines instead?

Comment: @Spudley Hum, there isn't any white space, so after find the buggy line I deleted a large amount pieces of code, I mean, like I haven't had no idea why was causing the behaviour I tried to compare the stylesheet with an old version (without the empty line) that working fine, and start copy-pasting paragraphs one by one. I only solved the error deleting the empty line. But, I will try put again the line, for test purposes (I`m afraid now, breaking the #1 rule for a programmer: "it works - don't touch" :D)

Comment: After few testing, I have edited the question. I'm pretty sure now is the "@import and empty rule" bug, but don't know why sometimes I can see it, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work (it did work once a while ago on a different bug),

try `.class{;}` it did once work but might not here.

Without the full (or at least partial) context of code it is hard to fix this type of bug.

Comment: Well, more than a fix I'm searching for an explanation of why I'm seeing this (in principle) fixed bug, or if it's officially documented by MS or something. Quick fix also pass for delete the empty line (after all it does nothing). Thanks anyway!